# How to control/handle/edit multiple objects?

Tags: c#, object

I'm quite new to OOP, but I've been toying around with C#. How does one control multiple objects?

Say that you have geometric objects (triangles, spheres, etc.) that all share one property, the (x,y,z) point co-ordinate in space. Now, moving each of the different objects alone is easy. For example rectangle.moveright(); and such

But say that I have n different objects that I want to move as a group, kinda like when marking icons/shortcuts on your desktop, and moving them around as a group.

How does one do this? Basically that you have a parent object that controls child objects

edit: A more specific example; Say that I have 10 objects of different kinds, I only want to move 5 of those with some function, later I want to move 4 other objects some other place. Always as a group

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple example. Note that the move functionality and points are not exact and would clearly need to be implemented in order to make this work.

Make an Interface and abstract class to allow for inheritance and polymorphism of the group of objects.

```
public interface IPositionable
{
 void Move(int x, int y, int z);
}

public abstract class Positionable : IPositionable
{
 public int x { get; set; }
 public int y { get; set; }
 public int z { get; set; }

 public void Move( int x, int y, int z )
 {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    this.z += z;
 }
}
```

Next Leverage these into the types of shapes you will use

```
public class Rectangle : Positionable{}
public class Triangle : Positionable{}
public class Square : Positionable{}
```

Once you have the basic part ready, you should use the **Mediator Pattern**.

```
public class PositionMediator
{
 public List<IPositionable> Group { get; set; }
 public PositionMediator()
 {
    Group = new List<IPositionable>();
    Group.Add(new Rectangle());
    Group.Add(new Triangle());
    Group.Add(new Square());
 }
 public void MoveGroup( int x, int y, int z )
 {
    foreach( var pos in Group )
    {
        pos.Move(x,y,z);
    }
 }
}
```

And once that is in place, you can control it like this:

```
void Main()
{
 var pm = new PositionMediator();
 pm.MoveGroup(1,2,3);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the mediator pattern, though I don't know I would tie my shapes together with the base class. It could very easily be abused.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent way to group objects in the manner you describe within OOP.  but there are several ways to achieve the same effect.

Lets say you set this up using an inheritance hierarchy.

You first define a base class named Shape, which only has only X,Y,Z implemented

```
public class Shape
{
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
    pulbic int Z {get;set;}
}
```

you then extend that class with several different shapes.

```
public class Triangle : Shape
{
    public string classification {get;set;}
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    public double area {get;set;}
}
```

you can then make a list of shapes, containing any type of object that extends shapes

```
List<Shape> ShapeSet;

ShapeSet.Add(myTriangle);
ShapeSet.Add(mySquare1);
ShapeSet.Add(mySquare4);
```

and you can then do something like this

```
foreach (Shape s in ShapeSet)
   s.X += 5;//move every shape in the set over by 5 along the X axis
```

The lists can be constructed on the fly, as needed, from the individual object instances.

This is only ONE way to accomplish the task, not necessarily the best one and not by any means the only one.  But it is a good example.  (the same thing can be done using an interface for shape, instead of a class)

Answer (score 1):

One was to look at this problem is to view it as trying to move real-world objects. If you have 10 marbles and you want to move five of them, what do you do? you can either move all of them, one at a time, to where you want them to go; or, you can group them and move them. Either way, they don't magically move themselves, they have to be told to move by something.

I would identity the union of behaviors in the group and expose those behaviors in some sort of interface (such as `IMoveable`). Then I would model the "mover." The mover would pick the objects in which it is interested (or you can give it the ones, and move the picking behavior to a "picker" object) and then you tell the mover where to go. It translates the command into commands for each of the objects to which it has a reference.

Example `IMoveable`:

```
public interface IMoveable
{
    void MoveTo(Position position);
    void MoveBy(int dx, int dy);
}
```

Example `Mover`:

```
public class Mover
{
    private List<IMoveable> _moveables = new List<IMoveable>();

    public void AddAsTarget(IMoveable moveable)
    {
        _moveables.Add(moveable); // Null checks, and such, yada...
    }

    public void Reposition(int dx, int dy)
    {
        foreach(var moveable in _moveables)
        {
            moveable.MoveBy(dx, dy);
        }
    }
}
```

Overall, it has to fit your use case. You can go insane with OOP but shouldn't model the real world. Just model until the problem is solved and is understandable. The harder part is determining whether to group objects by an interface or inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

All the objects you would want to move share something in common: They can be moved. The meaning of what moving means for a particular object can be different, but still, they are moveable.

One way to reflect this in the object structure would be to make all such object implement the same interface, call it `IMoveable` and then provide the implementation of the interface for every moveable object.

This way the rest of the code can call methods of this interface without really caring what specific object is being moved